# How to store the external dependencies of Gradle in SVN for my Android Studio Project?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android Studio project with many Gradle compile dependencies for Google Play, Android Support Lib, Firebase and some other libs.

I am not using the built in SVN Support of Android Studio but I added the source files manually to my SVN. Now I was wondering that all those source codes or libs of the external dependencies are not available to be stored with my SVN. That means that my SVN commits do not contain the "complete" source code or source+libs for my project.

What is the idea behind it? Will the external links like com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.1 will also work in 10 years from https://maven.google.com so there is now need to store this by myself? Or should I store some generated lib files? But where to find them?

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.1'
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the idea is that Maven repositories will be available forever, and the combination of an artifact ID and version number uniquely identifies a library so that it will never change in the future. Storing library files in version control is considered bad practice because it unnecessarily inflates the repository and makes it somewhat harder to update the versions.